# SSL securing for my laravel app with Let's Encrypt

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I have a site which I want to have HTTPS for, this is my first time doing something like this so bear with me.

I have a VPS with ubuntu and nginx as web server, I have followed this steps:

1- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

2 - sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx

3 - sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
     sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'

And I also have my dns set up and ready, let's say example.com ...

Now what command should I use?

I have seen like this:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d tudominio.com -d www.tudominio.com
```

but also like this:

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html/quickstart -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

I also have another question, in ubuntu I create symbolic link to enable my sites, but how can I take down indifinitely a site? should I do php artisan down or should I remove the sym link, adn hw do I do this?

which one should I use?

Comment: The first command should be fine. Please keep it to 1 question per question though.

Comment: The first command should work. you can try this tool also: https://zerossl.com